# Проблемы с line-height и прижатым футером

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html,
ul,
li,
div,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer,
.total-price {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.total-price {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #2f3239;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.total-price .total-price-step .step {
  background-color: #3b3f48;
  border-right: 1px solid #2f3239;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.total-price .total-price-step .step.inactive {
  color: #4f535b;
  background-color: #2f3239;
  border-right-color: #4f535b;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost {
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost span {
  display: inline;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost .price {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #cd9a2b;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost .price .price-small {
  color: #fff;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost .text-900 {
  display: none;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #cd9a2b;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cd9a2b;
}

.total-price .total-price-next span {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4f535b;
}

.total-price .total-price-next a {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(../img/icons/next-step.png) no-repeat center;
  background-color: #3b3f48;
}

.total-price .total-price-next.active span {
  color: #fff;
}

.total-price .total-price-next.active a {
  background-color: #cd9a2b;
}

.price {
  font-family: ProximaB;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.price .price-small {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="total-price">
    <div class="total-price-step">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="step">1</div>
        <div class="step">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total-price-cost row">
      <span class="text-full">Итоговая стоимость:</span>
      <span class="text-900">Сумма: </span>
      <span class="price">7 800 <b class="price-small">руб.</b></span>
      <a href="">Оплатить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Использовал хак для прижатия футера к низу отсюда: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Возникла такая проблема:

После нижнего блока появляется отступ во всех браузерах. Причём, если убрать у класса .total-price свойство line-height: 60px; и повесить это свойство на .total-price .step и .total-price-cost a, то отступ в chrome исчезнет. Но останется в Firefox и IE 10,11 в виде тоненькой полоски, намного тоньше, чем была до этого.

Дальше больше:

Если повесить line-height: 58px на .total-price-cost a (т.к. рамка у него по 1px), то отступ пропадёт и в Firefox, но в злосчастном IE останется тоненькая полоска.

И наконец, финал:

Если удалить всё содержимое из тега с классом .total-price, то отступ в Chrome и Firefox пропадёт даже если у класса .total-price будет свойство line-height: 60px, а вот в IE по-прежнему отступ останется.

Прошу помощи у гуру-верстальщиков, которые мне объяснят, откуда появляются такие различные баги с этим свойством и как с ними бороться. (особенно в ie 10,11)

P.S. Добавил для body цвет фона, чтобы было понятно, где эта самая полоска снизу.

Answer (score 1):

Замените `line-height` на 1:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html,
ul,
li,
div,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

//Footer hack
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer,
.total-price {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.total-price {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #2f3239;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.total-price .total-price-step .step {
  background-color: #3b3f48;
  border-right: 1px solid #2f3239;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.total-price .total-price-step .step.inactive {
  color: #4f535b;
  background-color: #2f3239;
  border-right-color: #4f535b;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost {
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost span {
  display: inline;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost .price {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #cd9a2b;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost .price .price-small {
  color: #fff;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost .text-900 {
  display: none;
}

.total-price .total-price-cost a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #cd9a2b;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cd9a2b;
}

.total-price .total-price-next span {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4f535b;
}

.total-price .total-price-next a {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(../img/icons/next-step.png) no-repeat center;
  background-color: #3b3f48;
}

.total-price .total-price-next.active span {
  color: #fff;
}

.total-price .total-price-next.active a {
  background-color: #cd9a2b;
}

.price {
  font-family: ProximaB;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.price .price-small {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="total-price">
    <div class="total-price-step">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="step">1</div>
        <div class="step">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total-price-cost row">
      <span class="text-full">Итоговая стоимость:</span>
      <span class="text-900">Сумма: </span>
      <span class="price">7 800 <b class="price-small">руб.</b></span>
      <a href="">Оплатить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Это то понятно, это похоже на то, что я описывал выше, даже немного хуже, т.к. "Итоговая стоимость" и "цена" начинают отображаться выше, чем мне нужно. И к тому же тонкая полоска в ie по-прежнему остаётся.

Comment: Меня интересует даже не столько решение, сколько причина проблемы.

Comment: Извиняюсь, немного не так выразился. Полоска в ie повляется с line-height: 1, только в случае наличия скролла на странице. Но всё равно, она же появляется.